# Changing Windows Azure Cloud Service IP Address

Tags: azure, geolocation, ip, azure-cloud-services

Does anybody know if it's possible to change the IP address of a site hosting on Windows Azure Cloud Services.

We currently have a site hosted in the 'North Europe' location, however the GEO IP of the IP Address assigned returns USA. This is causing problems with an API we have started using that can only be access within the UK checked via GEO IP Location.

Within the region of 'North Europe' however, there are a couple of IP ranges that have ip addresses that consistently return 'Dublin/UK' which will be ideal for what we need.

So, does anybody know if this is possible? we don't have technical support on the plan we use, which is why I'm asking here.

Thanks in Advance,
Bav

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to change the IP address. At least not without deleting the deployment and recreating (which would likely assign a new IP address).  That doesn't guarantee you'll get what you're after though.

This does seem to be a known issue though:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2014/05/10/microsoft-azure-datacenter-s-ip-location-shows-incorrect-location-when-using-ip-geolocation-services.aspx
- http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/11/windows-azures-use-of-non-us-ipv4-address-space-in-us-regions/

Azure support may be able to help, but that likely requires a support plan.  :(

Answer (score 0):

You normally can't control the public IP address of your cloud service. This is *partially*  controlled by the region you select, but not entirely.

As part of the most recent Azure update, however, you can reserve a public IP address that will never change as long as you keep the reservation. These are not free, but they're probably your only option.

See: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/

Now, this still won't let you pick your IP - but you could keep requesting reservations until you get one you like.

Lastly, as another answered suggested, there is no way to change the IP of a cloud service post-deployment. You must delete the deployment to get a new IP. (Or change network configuration, or rename the cloud service / get a new DNS name, etc.)